# Android start a new activity before another activity in backstack and clear activities above old activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack, android-navigation

I'm stuck with an Activity backstack question. Let's say I have 5 activities in my backstack: like Activity A, Activity B, Activity C, Activity D and Activity E. At some point I want the user to go to another Activity G, when pressed on the back button on Activity E. Activity G needs to be put after Activity B, so I want Activity C and Activity D removed from the backstack (otherwise the user would go to Activity D).

`Current situation A --> B --> C --> D --> E`

`Preferred situation A --> B --> G`

Now I understand I can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` when Activity G would have been in the backstack. But the Activity isn't. Also I don't want to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` because then Activities A and B would also be gone.

Another approach would be to put

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

within the manifest for Activities C and D, but this would make the user go back to Activity B every time the user pressed the back button from within Activity C or D.

Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: whats the issue with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP , its appropriate for u

Comment: You see Activity G isn't in the backstack yet, so there is nothing on top of Activity G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can try below

C ----startActivityForResult----------> D ---startActivityForResult--> E

handle onActivityResult with result accordingly to finish Activities, make sure its chained action calls
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start activity from **C->D** you put **finish();**

**Intent intent=new Intent(C.this,D.class);**

**startActivity(intent);**

**finish();**

same way for **D->G** this way it is possible.

Comment: In this case the user won't be able to go back to Activity C when in Activity D